# Can only scroll down half way in text view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have a text view that extends past the page and i need to be able to scroll down in that text view but it starts me out looking at the middle paragraph of the text and i can only scroll up about half way.

This is what i've done.

```
[aboutUsText setScrollEnabled:YES];
[aboutUsText setEditable:NO];
```

Comment: try to increase your content size

Comment: This is now the 3rd time you have posted this exact same question. You have deleted the first two. Please stop. Perhaps you should consider asking a better question instead of reposting over and over.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear but it sounds a lot like your UITextView extends past its superviews bounds. You might want to try and make sure it fits snuggly into it's superview like this:

`textView.frame = textView.superview.bounds;`

Then maybe make sure it stays that way by setting either constraints or simply the autoresizing mask like follows:

`textView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;`